# Vue 3 not updating input field

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

to the current problem, when this Vue page opens it fetches the data from my API. Only when I click 1 time in the webeite, it inserts the data into the form. How can I make it insert the data automatically?

```
    <script setup>
import { Dialog, DialogPanel, DialogTitle, TransitionChild, TransitionRoot, Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel } from '@headlessui/vue'
import { useModalStore } from '@/stores'
import { Countries } from '@/helpers'
import { Form, Field } from 'vee-validate'
import { UserDto } from '@/dtos'
import { CalendarIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/outline'
import moment from 'moment'
import { DatePicker } from 'v-calendar'
import axios from '@/axios'
require('yup-phone')

axios.get("user/get-by-id-async/" + useModalStore().showMemberAddEditModal.SelectedUserId).then(
    res => {
        UserDto.Id = res.data.id;
        UserDto.Role = res.data.role;
        UserDto.Password = res.data.password;
        UserDto.Mail = res.data.mail;
        UserDto.FirstName = res.data.firstName;
    })
<script >
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the code run when the page loads:

Inside your script setup import onMounted:

```
import {onMounted} from 'vue';
```

Then call it below:

```
onMounted(() => {
  axios.get("user/get-by-id-async/" + 
  useModalStore().showMemberAddEditModal.SelectedUserId).then(
    res => {
        UserDto.Id = res.data.id;
        UserDto.Role = res.data.role;
        UserDto.Password = res.data.password;
        UserDto.Mail = res.data.mail;
        UserDto.FirstName = res.data.firstName;
    })
})
```

Let me know if this works :)